# Alt text attributes not showing over portfolio images

Tags: posts, functions, customization

I´ve been searching almost all posts regarding this issue but haven´t found a solution for my theme. Maybe there´s a kind expert mind that can support me. I´m using a theme that doesn´t allow updates nor support. It´s a grid-based minimal design. As I´m a motion designer would like that when the viewer hover´s the cursor over the images on the page the information text displays as it used to, now it doesn´t happen anymore and I´m a bit frustrated as need showing my work to potential clients.

This is my website https://rafaelcalleja.com/ not sure if I should share anything else to get some advice?

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't allow updates"? You've got the PHP so you can edit it if you need to. If you mean it's not set up to support child themes (somehow?) then you could just fork the theme - change the name so that it won't get automatically updated and overwritten - and edit the templates in that version to do what you want.

Comment: Hi @Rup thanks for your response, what I mean is I bought a Theme called "Base" and now it doesn´t allow any further support nor updates from the place I bought it. I´m not very good or experiences with this and i´m not sure or don´t know how i could eit my theme so the title of each project gets displayed as the cursor "hovers" over each image that represents each project. It used to do but now it doesn´t and i don´t seem to be able to find where to fix this.. do u think you could help me? would really appreciate it as it´s the only thing I need on my theme. Thanks in advance